# How to check if all Dict elements meet a certain criteria in Elm?

Tags: dictionary, elm

In Javascript, to check if all hash elements meet a certain condition, one could do this:

```
var dict = {
  elm: 4,
  language: 7,
  is: 3,
  awesome: 11
};

function allEven(dict) {
  for (var key in dict) {
    if (dict[key] % 2 === 1) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(allEven(dict));
```

The main point here is that we stop the calculation as soon as we can.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a `Dict.all` function in Elm.

Another option, I guess, is to convert the `Dict` into a `List` and use `List.all`. But, I'd like to avoid creating the `List`, if possible.

How would you implement this short-circuit mechanism in Elm?

Answer (score 1):

In general, we just construct functions like these using folds:

```
import Dict

dictAll : (comparable -> Bool) -> Dict.Dict comparable b -> Bool
dictAll predicate = 
  Dict.foldr (\key _ soFar -> soFar && predicate key) True
```

This iterates through each element in the dictionary, and checks if it meets the predicate and all previous elements have met the predicate.

You can do the same thing with "any" by switching True with False, and `&&` with `||`.

Comment: As far as I understand, folds won't short circuit the process. If `soFar` becomes `False`, I'd like to stop processing.

Comment: Ahh, that's my mistake, I missed that aspect of your question, I read the mailing list email but not fully the SO post!

Comment: I don't think the "< O(n) in some cases" part is possible. However, unlike lists, the order is arbitrary so shot circuiting is less reliable. I wouldn't worry about the performance.

Comment: @mgold Why short circuiting won't be reliable if I'm testing whether all elements meet a certain criteria? The order shouldn't matter.

Comment: Oh, it will be reliably correct. But it's possible I'll visit all passing elements before a failing one, unlike a list where the order is fixed.